# Is it a good idea to have an arrow pointing down for more content /

Tags: website-design

In the website at the bottom of the site there is a table. But I need to add two more tables with content. Is it a good idea to put an arrow pointing down after the first table so that when pressed it shows the other tables ?

Or is there a better way to do this , that would provide a better user experience?

Comment: post a mock of what you are thinking and your efforts so far...

Answer (score 1):

It may be confusing with 2 other actions:

1. *Download*. As you mentioned it's a table, tables frequently can be downloaded as XLS, CSV r other formats and part of download icons include arrow pointing down.
2. *Continuity of the same table*. Thread design usually includes hints that scrolling down will reveal more data from the same type.

It's hard to answer it without knowing the explicit purpose of other tables, why do you want to hide them in a first place and knowledge of where you would like to place this tables. Would it be next page or down at the same page, but in general I would suggest alternatives with more textual explanation.